# Change a Toolbox for new component

Tags: c#, components

ALL,
I have created a new component in Visual Studio inside the solution I'm working on my application.
Now I want that component to appear in the Toolbox of Visual Studio.

How can I do that?

I tried to close and re-open the solution and its not there.

Thank you.

Comment: have you done a google search on this and how to add custom controls to the palette ?

Comment: If it's in the current solution, all you have to do is rebuild the solution and the component should show up in the toolbox.

Comment: @LarsTech, Should but does not. Please see my reply to DelegateX.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing wrong.  I did an Add Component, saved the file, rebuild solution, and it's now sitting in my Components toolbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you rebuild your solution after creating the control, Visual Studio automatically adds the control by creating a new category named after your application. If for some reason, VS doesn't adds it, you can manually do it by right clicking in the toolbox and choosing Customize. A dialog box will appear listing assemblies to be added to the toolbox. Since you have a custom control, you need to browse for your control's DLL (You have it under Bin folder of your application). This will add the control to the toolbox.

Comment: apparently there is no DLL in the my_project/bin/debug folder. Only exe, pdb vshost.exe and manifest. I created by selecting "Project->Add Component.." and gave the component a name. Then in the code I change an inheritance from Component to "System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox".

Comment: Nevermind. I selected exe file and it showed up. Apprently VS does not produce a DLL but uses built-in technique. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You right click on the toolbox and choose "Customize" , you will have a dialog that lets you browse to the assembly of your control .